# NextJS a page fails to load with no logs on vercel only

Tags: next.js, vercel

A basic html page fails to load and provides no logs. You can see the page deployed [here](https://boveticonstruction.vercel.app/bg/apartment/17/apartment-ap-v04). I attempted to narrow down the problematic piece but it turns out that just one more  makes the page getting stuck, which doesn't make sense to me. The problem doesn't happen locally. There aren't any useful logs in Vercel's runtime logs. No error occur during the build phase either. I have been stuck on this issue for days and really don't see any useful action item. I am not sure what can be shared here as a code sample, perhaps the following:

```html
"use client";

...

return (
 <motion.div
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 2 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 3, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
    >
      <div className="container" style={{margin: 20}}>
        {/* Back navigation */}
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-8 np">
            <div className="py-4">
            <span className="hover ps-4" onClick={() => history.back()}>
              <i style={{marginRight: 10}} class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left"></i>
              КЪМ ЕТАЖНОТО РАЗПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ
            </span>
              <div className="row">


             {/*   <div className="col-5" style={{marginLeft: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                  <h2><b>{name}</b></h2>
                </div>*/}




                <div className="row col-7 d-flex justify-content-start" style={{marginTop: 20}}>

                  <div className="col-2 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
                    <span><b>ВХОД</b>  <p style={{marginTop: 8}}>{entrance}</p></span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-1 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-4 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block text-center">
                    <span><b>С ОБЩИ ЧАСТИ</b></span> <p style={{marginTop: 8}}>{totalArea} m2</p>
                  </div>


                  <div className="col-1 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
                  </div>

                  <div className="col-2 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
                    <span><b>ИЗЛОЖЕНИЕ</b></span> <p style={{marginTop: 8}}>{direction && direction.title_bg ? direction.title_bg : null}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>



            </div>

            <div className="col-10 d-xxl-none d-xl-none">

              <div className="row justify-content-between">
                <div className="col text-start">
                  <span style={{marginLeft: 12}}><b>ВХОД</b>  <p style={{marginLeft: 12}}>{entrance}</p></span>
                </div>

                <div className="col text-center">
                  <span><b>С общи части</b></span> <p>{totalArea} m2</p>
                </div>


                <div className="col text-end">
                  <span style={{marginRight: 8}}><b>Изложение</b></span> <p style={{marginRight: 8}}>{direction && direction.title_bg ? direction.title_bg : null}</p>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>


          </div>
          {/* desktop floor picker */}
          <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-4 py-5 border-secondary">

            <div className="row">


  
              <div className="col-10" style={{paddingRight: 0}}>
                <div className="row justify-content-between" style={{width: '100%', marginRight: 0}}>
                  <div className="col-6 mt-5">
                                    <span style={{display: 'flex',
                                      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                                      alignItems: 'flex-start'}}>
                                        <strong>
                                            <h5><b>{price !== 0 ? (price??"").toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ") : ''}</b> {price!==0 ? 'EUR' : ''}</h5>
                                        </strong>
                                        <sup>{price!==0 ? ' С ДДС' : ''}</sup>
                                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col d-flex align-self-end" style={{paddingRight: 0}}>
                    <div style={{marginRight: 0}} className={`ms-auto apt-${getParkingStatusStringStyle(status)}`}>{getParkingStatusString(status)}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



            </div>

          </div>


          <div className={'row text-center'}>

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">

                <div className="d-none d-md-block">
                  <div className="row">
              
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>



        </div>

      </div>
    </motion.div>
    
    )
```